# How to find all soft links (symbolic links) in current directory?

Tags: bash, symbolic-link, ls, shell-script, ln

Question relates to shell-scripting in `bash`.

How to check with a script **which files** within the current directory are soft links?

In case I have used the wrong term, when I say [soft links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link), I am referring to files created using `ln -s`.

The only thing I have managed to think of is to evaluate `ls -la` as an expression, and parse its results, but obviously this is not the best solution.

Comment: They're referred to as "symbolic links" (as opposed to "hard links").

Comment: Righto, I knew I probably got the term wrong, thanks for the heads up

Comment: Soft link is just fine as well, but with a space. :-) (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See ['CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS'](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) in `man bash` – in this case you want `-h`:

```
for file in *
do
  if [ -h "$file" ]; then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_68.html - For conditional expressions makes for a better read than the man page.

Comment: Thanks @Polsy and @Manos! `test -h` is what I wanted!

Answer (score 14):

You might not really need a script. To show any symbolic links in just the current folder, without recursing into any child folder:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -print
```

Or, to get some more info, use one of:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec ls -ld {} +
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
```

To tell *if* a file is a symbolic link, one can use `readlink`, which will output nothing if it's not a symbolic link. The following example is not quite useful, but shows how `readlink` ignores normal files and folders. Use one of:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -exec readlink {} +
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 readlink
```

Note that the above `-exec ... +` and `xargs ...` are much faster than `-exec ... \;`. Like:

```
time find /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec ls -ld {} \;
real 0m0.372s
user 0m0.087s
sys  0m0.163s

time find /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec ls -ld {} +
real 0m0.013s
user 0m0.004s
sys  0m0.008s

time find /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 -type l -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
real 0m0.012s
user 0m0.004s
sys  0m0.009s
```

Comment: I liked Polsy's answer better, still +1 for you, since I might need to do it outside a shell script some day.

Comment: You don't necessarily need xargs. You could just use find . -maxdepth 1 -exec readlink {} \;

Comment: True, @stib, but `xargs` is *a lot* faster on my Mac; see my edit. But I learned something new today: there's also `+` instead of `\;` (Though some claim that [this has/had problems](http://www.sunmanagers.org/pipermail/summaries/2005-March/006255.html) with `grep`.)