# How to display the size in human readable format in the find command

Tags: bash

I am trying to display the filze size in human readable format in following find command

```
 find $BASE_DIR/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME -type f -printf      "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | 
 sort -nr | 
 head -n $NUMFILES >> $TESTFILE
```

My function to find large files looks like this.  It takes in $1 as an argument in order to pass the base directory path to the find command.

```
 function find_files {
 #echo "In find files"
 # $1 = base directory from where to start the search

 find $1/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr | head -n $NUMFILES >> $TESTFILE

 if [[ -s $TESTFILE ]] ; 
 then 
   echo "***********************************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
   echo "***********************************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
   echo "***********************************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
   echo "***********************************************************************" >> $DUMPFILE
   #cat $TESTFILE
   cat $TESTFILE >> $DUMPFILE
   rm $TESTFILE
   return 0
 else
   return 1
 fi
 }
```

Comment: First of all, will you please phrase your question in the form of a question?  :-)

Comment: `$BASE_DIR/` and `$1/` don’t need the trailing slashes, but they really should be in quotes, as in: `find "$1" -user …`

Answer (score 2):

Use the -exec option for find (Don't forget to end with \;)
If you require only part of the information from your exec command, parse with awk.

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME -type f -exec /bin/ls -hl {} \;
```

Use another command if you don't want human readable output of ls, or awk it like so

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME -type f -exec /bin/ls -hl {} \; | awk '{ print $5,$9 }'
```

The trickiest parts of find's exec are using {} as the result item for what is found, and the command must end in \;
If you have a chain of commands on the same line separated with ;
You will need to end your find and then add a ; so there are 2, like
    some command; find $BASE_DIR/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME -type f -exec /bin/ls -hl {} \;; some command;

Comment: As for *"and the command must end in `\;`"*, note that `-exec ... +` (and `xargs ...`) is much faster than `-exec ... \;`. (Test yourself with the `time` command, or see [some other test](http://superuser.com/questions/71163/how-to-find-all-soft-links-symbolic-links-in-current-directory/71231#71231).)

Comment: Thanks @Arjan. I had not previously used + instead of \; so I read the man page on it. The key difference seems to be that instead of running the command once per match, it runs it once with all matches as arguments.
find . -iname "*.php" -exec php -l {} +
No syntax errors detected in ./1.php
find . -iname "*.php" -exec php -l {} \;
No syntax errors detected in ./1.php
No syntax errors detected in ./2.php
find . -type f -exec /bin/ls -hl {} + | awk '{ print $5,$9 }'
17 ./1.php
17 ./2.php
find . -type f -exec /bin/ls -hl {} \; | awk '{ print $5,$9 }'
17 ./1.php
17 ./2.php

Comment: I tried the following command but it gave me slightly different result. It gave a list of large files but missed even larger files. find /proj/platform_emulation3/kv/cp/ -user $USER -size +3000k -mtime +3 -exec /bin/ls -hl {} \; | awk '{ print $5,$9 }' | sort -nr | head -n 5

Answer (score 2):

The subtlety here is the `sort`, you cannot (easily & correctly) sort human-readable numbers
(unless you have `sort` from *GNU coreutils* >= 7.5, it supports a `-h` option, e.g. `du -h | sort -h`).

Save the following to `hr.awk`:

```
BEGIN { split("KMGTPEZY",suff,//)}
{
  match($0,/([0-9]+)[ \t](.*)/,bits)
  sz=bits[1]+0; fn=bits[2]
  i=0; while ((sz>1024)&&(i<length(suff))) { sz/=1024;i++ }
  if (i) printf("%.3f %siB %s\n",sz,suff[i],fn)
  else   printf("%3i B %s\n",sz,fn)
}
```

Then you can do:

```
find $BASE_DIR/ -user $USER -size +$LOWERSIZELIMIT -mtime +$MY_MTIME \
  -type f -printf "%s %p\n" 2> /dev/null | sort -nr |
  gawk -f hr.awk | head -n $NUMFILES >> $TESTFILE
```

The gawk script accepts `find ... -printf "%s %p\n"` as input, and converts the first field to human-readable size with suffix (in IEC 2<sup>10</sup> units).

See also this popular question: https://serverfault.com/questions/62411/how-can-i-sort-du-h-output-by-size